How to retry indefinitely in spring kafka listener?
Have a question. Would to retry a batch indefinitely using a spring kafka listener @KafkaLister.
The way I tried was by having the listener container with immediate_manual acknowledgment and then not acknowledging the batch based a condition. However, it seems that the batch is only redelivered when the app is restarted so. How do I do that?
Note: throwing an exception doesn't work because after a certain number of attempts it will send it to DLT. I don't want this.
Regards.
Not acknowledging the batch.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html#retrying-batch-eh. Also see DefaultErrorHandler(BackOff backOff) which can be applied for a new FixedBackOff() with a maxAttempts = Long.MAX_VALUE - infinite.

Tough to say exactly without more context, but the default behavior of Acknowledgment.nack(Duration sleep) is to reprocess after the sleep duration. So for example, assuming you've configured your ack mode ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and auto commit to false (i.e consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false), the following should behave as you're hoping, retrying every 5 seconds indefinitely:
@KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic")
public void consume(String messageValue, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers, Acknowledgment ack)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    try {
        ...stuff that could throw IOException or InterruptedException exception...

        // safe to acknowledge since we haven't thrown an exception
        ack.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ack.nack(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        // I suppose you can remove this throw if you really need to, but that seems a bit odd
        throw e;
    }
}

I know you said "Note: throwing an exception doesn't work because after a certain number of attempts it will send it to DLT. I don't want this.", and I've thrown an exception in the example given but if you don't want that exception to be handled by the DLT, either remove the DLT functionality (maybe you're unnecessarily using the @RetryableTopic annotation?) or exclude that exception from the DLT functionality (for example by configuring RetryableTopic.exclude() with exceptions you'd want excluded). Or you can remove the throw, as I mentioned in the code snippet but to me that seems a bit risky. Hope this helps.
